# When creating a colorbox from a colorbox, how do I send POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

Inside my colorbox, I am calling this to make another colorbox:

```
$.colorbox({href:myurl});
```

I have a valid url in place of myurl.  I am trying to see how to send one or more POST variables to this url.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply the variables you like to send via the data-property

```
$.colorbox({href:myurl,
            data:{someVariable:'someValue',anotherVariable:'anotherValue'}
  });
```

When data is an object, it will be sended via POST, when it's a string via GET